# Making object parallel (fit) to detected AR plane

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality, measure

I tried the Measure App on iOS and I noticed that the reticle automatically fits the detected plane (for horizontal planes the reticle will be horizontal and for vertical planes, it will be vertical). Even for the inclined plane, it will rotate to fit it as it is a part of it.

I am building an AR application using AR foundation.

Currently, I am just rotate my reticle on vertical and horizontal planes using this code:

```
if (_arRaycastManager.Raycast(screenCenter, s_Hits, TrackableType.Planes))
{
    var hit = s_Hits[0];
    if (_arPlaneManager.GetPlane(s_Hits[0].trackableId).alignment == PlaneAlignment.HorizontalUp ||
        _arPlaneManager.GetPlane(s_Hits[0].trackableId).alignment == PlaneAlignment.HorizontalDown)
    {
        Reticle.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(90, 0, 0);
    }
    else if (_arPlaneManager.GetPlane(s_Hits[0].trackableId).alignment == PlaneAlignment.Vertical)
    {
        Reticle.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    }

    Reticle.transform.position = hit.pose.position;
}
```

Is there a way to implement the behaviour of measure app reticle in my application.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but currently you are hard setting `0, 0, 0` or `90, 0, 0` as world space rotation.

This of course ignores completely how the planes are actually rotated within the Unity world coordinate system.

I think what you rather want to use is simply

```
Reticle.transform.rotation = hit.pose.rotation;
```

or if you can get the plane itself you could also use its normal like e.g.

```
Reticle.transform.up = _arPlaneManager.GetPlane(hit.trackableId).normal;
```

depending on the axis your Reticle should match the normal on.

Comment: For: ```Reticle.transform.rotation = hit.pose.rotation;``` most of the time (about 65%) it is not giving good results (reticle is vertical on horizontal planes and vice versa). In some cases, it gives the desired results. Do you think the problem is with ```var hit = s_Hits[0];```?